# Is it OK to use Documentations's improvement requests as a "todo list"

Tags: support, documentation

As Documentation does not have a "todo list", the closest thing that came to my mind was Improvement requests; so is it ok to use them as a todo list?

Comment: There is a "Requested Topics" list/tracker, so I assume you are talking about things to be done *within* an existing topic?

Comment: I'm talking about "improvement requests". @CodyGray

Comment: i mean... as long as you agree with them. Not all requests are are good ones.

Comment: As long as it's a todo list that anyone can cross off todo items from. In other words, the todo items have to make enough sense that anyone can fulfill them, not just you.

Comment: Fwiw, I have used them that way (with the caveat that they are written so anyone can address them, as Mike said).